# PHP is not working after upgrading macOS from High Sierra to Mojave

Tags: php, apache2, macos-mojave

After upgrading macOS from High Sierra to Mojave, PHP is not running it's showing PHP codes in client side as bellow.

```
<?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

Currently, php5.6 is installed.
My server directory was at

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents
```

also, I tried at

```
/Users/username/Sites
```

but, still not working.

Comment: This is similar but not the same question.